# iTunes Home Sharing only works one way between 2 PC's on the same LAN

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8.1, itunes, home-sharing

I've got two computers, **A** with Windows 7 Home Premium, and **B** with Windows 8.1. Both are using the same account. A can "see" the library in B, but **B can't see the library in A** (it doesn't show up in the left panel in iTunes).

FYI

- When I run in both PCs the command

  > telnet 127.0.0.1 3689

  I get that port 3689 (required for this feature) is open.
- Both are using the same router and are joined to a HomeGroup.
- iTunes version 11.1.5.5 on both computers.
- **EDIT**: I tried "seeing" the library with another computer running Windows 7, and it can see the library in B but not in A... which suggests it's an issue with computer A.

Comment: Firewall software?

Comment: McAfee Internet Security. I looked around but haven't found a way to see the firewall settings :s I don't really want to uninstall it cuz it came with the computer...

Comment: That's on computer B. On A I've got MSE and AVG Free 2014